# difference between "lickspittle" and "sycophant"

Tags: meaning

**Lickspittle** is defined as:

> a person who behaves obsequiously to those in power.

whereas **Sycophant** is defined as:

> a person who acts obsequiously towards someone important ***in order to gain advantage***

Is this to say that a lickspittle is not looking for favors and has no ulterior motive for his obsequious mien (unlike the sycophant)?

Answer (score 2):

A characteristic of a sycophant is the search for personal returns by flattering influencial people. A lickspittle generally exhibits just a  more "servile" attitude.

***[Sycophant](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sycophant)***:,

> - ***is a person who tries to win favor from wealthy or influential people by flattering them***. Also known as brown-nosers, teacher's pets or suck-ups.
> - *Sycophant is from Latin sycophanta, from Greek sykophantēs, from sykon "fig" and phainein "to show, make known." The original sense was that of an informer, a person who gives information about criminal activities. "Showing the fig" was a vulgar gesture made by sticking the thumb between two fingers. The gesture was used to taunt an opponent or to make an accusation against someone.* (vocabulary.com)

***[Lickspittle](http://judyhagey.com/word-of-the-week-lickspittle/)***:

> - ***is a compound word, combining two Old English words — lick and spittle,***  neither particularly attractive activities. Spittle brings to mind the mixture of saliva and tobacco that cowboys are prone to hack up into – what else – a spittoon. ***Both meanings are familiar: lick—to run the tongue over and spittle — a derivation of spit. But combine the two and you have one of many variations of a derogatory term for someone who flatters those in authority.***  In elementary school we knew him/her as a brownnoser or an apple polisher. As an adult you might choose a less euphemistic term: Weingarten’s suckup, or sycophant, toady, lackey, or now that you know what it means — a lickspittle. ***The Free Dictionary calls a lickspittle a flattering or servile person. Servile – of or befitting a slave – captures the idea of someone bowing and scraping to the master.***  The subordinate who feels the need to flatter his/her superiors is in a form of bondage just as much as a slave is. (judyhagey.com)